# Springboot - convert JSON to JAVA

Tags: json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I need to obtain a currency exchange rate from a rest API into my spring boot application and convert the JSON response to Java class. The API will give me the response as below:-

```
{
    "USD_INR": {
        "val": 71.884966
    }
}
```

The code is as shown below:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public float hello(){

     ExchangeRate exchangeRate = restTemplate.getForObject("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=Source_Target&compact=y",ExchangeRate.class);
     return exchangeRate.getSource_Target().getVal();
  }
}
```

-

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ExchangeRate {
Source_Target SourceTargetObject;

  public Source_Target getSource_Target() {
      return SourceTargetObject;
  }


  public void setSource_Target(Source_Target SourceTargetObject) {
      this.SourceTargetObject = SourceTargetObject;
  }
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Source_Target {
private float val;

  public float getVal() {
    return val;
  }

  public void setVal(float val) {
    this.val = val;
  }
}
```

After executing the REST call, I am getting null exception. Nothing is returned. I am not able to figure out the issue here. Please help

Comment: can you post the exact `NullPointerException` stack trace to your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jsonscheme2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for generate java beans from json easily.

JSON:

```
{
"USD_INR": {
    "val": 71.884966
}
```

}

Corresponding Java bean :

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"USD_INR"
})
public class Example implements Serializable
{

@JsonProperty("USD_INR")
private USDINR uSDINR;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private final static long serialVersionUID = -932753391825750904L;

@JsonProperty("USD_INR")
public USDINR getUSDINR() {
return uSDINR;
}

@JsonProperty("USD_INR")
public void setUSDINR(USDINR uSDINR) {
this.uSDINR = uSDINR;
}

public Example withUSDINR(USDINR uSDINR) {
this.uSDINR = uSDINR;
return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public Example withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
return this;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.USDINR.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"val"
})
public class USDINR implements Serializable
{

@JsonProperty("val")
private Double val;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private final static long serialVersionUID = -6384976748235176082L;

@JsonProperty("val")
public Double getVal() {
return val;
}

@JsonProperty("val")
public void setVal(Double val) {
this.val = val;
}

public USDINR withVal(Double val) {
this.val = val;
return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public USDINR withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
return this;
}

}
```

Comment: @JsonProperty("USD_INR") - Can't give like this because the property changes with different Source & target currencies..

Answer (score 1):

Your ExchangeRate class should be:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ExchangeRate {
    @JsonProperty("USD_INR")
    Source_Target SourceTargetObject;

    public Source_Target getSource_Target() {
        return SourceTargetObject;
    }

    public void setSource_Target(Source_Target SourceTargetObject) {
        this.SourceTargetObject = SourceTargetObject;
    }
```

Then your Source_Target class should be:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Source_Target {
    @JsonProperty("val")
    private float val;

    public float getVal() {
         return val;
    }

    public void setVal(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Please beware of your class naming convention. I would rename `Source_Target` to `SourceTarget` to follow Java naming convention

Comment: @JsonProperty("USD_INR") - Can't give like this because the property changes with different Source & target currencies..

Answer (score 0):

You create a custom map:

```
public class ExchangeRate extends HashMap<String, ExchangeRateValue> implements Serializable {        
}

public class ExchangeRateValue implements Serializable {

    private float val;

    public float getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
 ExchangeRate exchangeRate = restTemplate.getForObject("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=Source_Target&compact=y", ExchangeRate.class);
 float data = exchangeRate.get("USD_INR").getVal();
```